# KivyMD cannot find reference "FocusBehavior"

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I was curious what is focus behavior and visited the official page (KivyMD) and took the first [example](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behaviors/focus/#kivymd.uix.behaviors.focus_behavior.FocusBehavior). Then I found out that FocusBehavior can't be imported. PyCharm recommended me to create class 'Focus Behavior' in *'**init**.py'* but it doesn't seem to be the solution. I have already reinstalled kivy and kivymd, but still, it cannot find a reference 'FocusBehavior'.
What should I do?

> from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RectangularElevationBehavior, FocusBehavior
> ImportError: cannot import name 'FocusBehavior' from 'kivymd.uix.behaviors' (C:\Users\Kadel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is wrong. Try using this import:

```
from kivymd.uix.behaviors.focus_behavior import FocusBehavior
```